# Remove a leading string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to build one RegEx to remove leading "The" or "A" or "An" and "spaces" from a given string.

For example, the given string is:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

With Regex I want the leading "The" to be removed and return just

> quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

I tried (added from a comment)

```
^*(?<=[The|An|A]\s){1}.*
```

It is working fine but in one scenario it is not returning expected result. Please see the scenarios below.

> Input: The quick brown fox --> Result = quick brown fox
>
> Input: A quick brown fox --> Result = quick brown fox
>
> Input: In A sunny day --> Result = A sunny day (expected is In a sunny
>   day.. as the string is not starting with A)
>
> Input: American An bank --> Result = An bank (expected is American An
>   bank.. as the string is not starting with An)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: More importantly, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 10):

What have you tried by yourself? What you want to achieve is not difficult, try e.g. [this tutorial on Regular-Expresions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

You are thinking much to complicated. Try this:

```
^(The|An|A)\s+
```

and replace with the empty string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33h31)

`^` matches the start of the string.

`(The|An|A)` An alternation, matches the first fitting alternative.

`\s+` matches at least one following whitespace.

Changes

> The quick brown fox
>
> A quick brown fox
>
> In A sunny day
>
> American An bank

To

> quick brown fox
>
> quick brown fox
>
> In A sunny day
>
> American An bank

Comment: I tried with this regex. ^*(?<=[The|An|A]\s){1}.*

It is working fine but in one scenario it is not returning expected result. Please see the scenarios below.
**Input:** The quick brown fox --> Result = quick brown fox
**Input:** A quick brown fox  --> Result = quick brown fox
**Input:** In A sunny day --> Result = A sunny day (expected is In a sunny day.. as the string is not starting with A)
**Input:** American An bank --> Result = An bank (expected is American An bank.. as the string is not starting with An).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete one-line in perl:

```
perl -e 'my $a = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"; $a =~ s/^\s*(?:The|An|A)\s+//gi; print $a;'
```

The part that does the replace is:

```
$a =~ s/^\s*(?:The|An|A)\s+//gi;
```

The regex that matches your words and spaces is `/^\s*(?:The|An|A)\s+/`

Comment: This regex is retrieving those characters from given string. But i want the string without them.

Comment: it is not retrieving them ( because of the *non-capturing* `(?:..)` construct ). It is replacing the matching part with empty string. Depending on the language you use, the replace might have a different syntax