# Trim a string from a string

Tags: c#, string, trim

So the normal way to trim something from a string is by trimming it by the character.

For example:

```
string test = "Random Text";
string trimmedString = test.Trim(new Char[] { 'R', 'a', 'n'});
Console.WriteLine(trimmedString);
//the output would be "dom Text"
```

But instead of doing this, is there a way to just completely remove the combined characters "Ran" from the string?

For example:

```
string test = "Random Text";
string trimmedString = test.Trim(string "Ran");
Console.WriteLine(trimmedString);
//the output would be "dom Text"
```

Now, the code above gives an error, but was wondering if something like this is possible, thank you!

Comment: string.Replace() ....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Remove** like this:

```
string test = "Random Text";
string textToTrim = "Ran";

if (test.StartsWith(textToTrim))
    test = test.Remove(0, textToTrim.Length);
if (test.EndsWith(textToTrim))
    test = test.Remove(test.Length - textToTrim.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to an array of chars, like this:

```
string trimmedString = test.Trim("Ran".ToArray());
```

However note that, trimming that way will not take care of the exact match (by order of the characters), so if your `test` is `"aRndom Text"`, it will still be trimmed to just `"dom Text"`.

If you want to trim the string by exact matching, you can use some code like this:

```
public static class TrimStringExtensions {
    public static string Trim(this string s, string toBeTrimmed){
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(toBeTrimmed)) return s;
         if(s.StartsWith(toBeTrimmed)){
              s = s.Substring(toBeTrimmed.Length);
         }
         if(s.EndsWith(toBeTrimmed)){
              s = s.Substring(0,s.Length - toBeTrimmed.Length);
         }
         return s;
    }
}
```

You can also use `Regex` for this:

```
public static class TrimStringExtensions {
     public static string Trim(this string s, string toBeTrimmed){
          if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(toBeTrimmed)) return s;
          var literal = Regex.Escape(toBeTrimmed);
          return Regex.Replace(s, $"^{literal}|{literal}$", "");
     }
}
```

Use it:

```
string trimmedString = test.Trim("Ran");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see several ways of doing it depending on your needs.

## A. What you do, but tiny bit smarter

```
string trimmedString = test.Trim("Ran".ToArray()); //Or TrimStart or TrimEnd
```

## B. Replace

```
string trimmedString = test.Replace("Ran", "");
```

This would remove "Ran" anywhere in the string.

## C. Replace only first occurrence

Please see [C# - Simplest way to remove first occurrence of a substring from another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201595/c-sharp-simplest-way-to-remove-first-occurrence-of-a-substring-from-another-st).

## D. Regular expression

Please see [Remove a leading string using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495497/remove-a-leading-string-using-regular-expression#14495608)